# title not showing up in queryset when __str__ method was used (django ORM)

Tags: python, django

Inside this `Django` tutorial i'm learning to create a blog site. Right now, we are at the point where we are using the `Django` ORM to interact with the database. I was following every step and i hit a wall at queryset, where the item name isn't showing up, and this was after i did this:

```
def __str__(self):
return self.title
```

the output that i get when i type

```
 Narticle.objects.all() is 
queryset Narticle:Narticle object(1) instead of 
<queryset [<Narticle: 'hello world']>
```

my steps are below this model:

my model for narticle is

```
from django.db import models


class Narticle(models.Model):
  title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug= models.SlugField()
  body= models.TextField(max_length= 100)
  date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
```

i entered the following on the command line:

```
from narticle.model import Narticle
```

i typed Narticle and i got

```
<class 'narticle.models.Narticle' >
```

i then entered the following

```
Narticle.objects.all()
```

and i got

```
<queryset[]>
```

i then typed

```
narticle= Narticle()
```

then

```
narticle
```

which gave me

```
Narticle: Narticle object(none)
```

i then typed

```
narticle.title = "hello world"
```

which was followed by

```
Narticle.objects.all()
```

Which gave me

```
< queryset [<Narticle: Nartice object (1)>]>
```

i typed 
    narticle.save()

i then exited command line,and then in models.py of narticle i typed

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.title
```

i then went back to command line and repeated the process of importing Narticle

Then i typed 
    Narticle.objects.all()

which gave me

```
< queryset [<Narticle: Nartice object (1)>]>
```

instead of

```
 <queryset [<Narticle: 'hello world']>
```

oh and why is it that the word "none", and then (1), when i make an entry'like this

```
<Narticle: Narticle object (none)>
```

or in case of an entry

```
<Narticle: Narticle object (1)>
```

instead of

```
 <Narticle: Narticle object>
```

Comment: Can you try printing `str(narticle)` and see what it says?  This may be the interpreter calling `__repr__` on your object instead of `__str__`.  Also is the `def __str__` method actually a part of the Narticle model?  It's missing from the source in your Narticle model.

Comment: yes it is a part of the model, i tried and nothing happened,same output

Comment: what version of python and django are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I got it, and I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

```
class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  body = models.TextField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

This is an example and its working fine with ORM
The **str** function is to be indented such that its inside the class function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I forgot to indent the 'def **str**(self)' :)

Comment: Please, could you provide a complete code example? I did not understand if I had to indent `def __str__(self)` or indent he lines that follow that one line. Also careful with formatting, include it as code or "_" will be used as markdown syntax